# PHP money_format

Tags: php

Hola estoy recibiendo como parámetros un string o entero, no importa...he usado number_format en PHP para mostrar cantidades, quiero probar money_format  pero tengo problema al querer encontrar formato numérico para mi país. Ejemplo: `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US')`

Hay algún formato para la moneda de Guatemala?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar cual es el formato de la moneda de Guatemala en la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El identificador de configuración regional para Guatemala es [`es_GT`](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-GT/)

Para usarlo podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
// Guatemala
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_GT');
echo money_format('%i', 1234).'<br/>';

// Argentina
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_AR');
echo money_format('%i', 1234).'<br/>';

// Estados Unidos
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', 1234).'<br/>';

?>
```

[Demo aquí](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vhxb-k49p)

Comment: Excelente...gracias!